# Python requests.get function what is the percent symbol doing here?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using API documentation with the following snippet:

```
    r = requests.get("%slogin?username=%s&password=%s"
                     % (BASEURL, username, password))
```

What is the % symbol doing here?  I have never passed this into .get before and I am not sure what it is doing.

Answer (score 2):

From this [String formatting: % vs. .format vs. f-string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/string-formatting-vs-format-vs-f-string-literal)

- Python <2.6: "Hello %s" % name
- Python 2.6+: "Hello {}".format(name)   (uses str.format)
- Python 3.6+: f"{name}"   (uses f-strings)

it is there for formatting the string url

Comment: Thanks I was looking in the docs for requests.get() :( Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do string formatting in Python.  It doesn't have anything specifically to do with the `get()` function.

The first `%s` takes on the value of the first variable `BASEURL`.  The second `%s` takes on the value of the second variable `username`, and so on.

See https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation for more examples.

Comment: Thanks I was looking in the docs for requests.get() :( Appreciate your help